# save as pdf using chrome with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf

Chrome allows users to hit Ctrl + P and choose 'Save to PDF'.

Is it possible to have this function through an javascript?

Like if click on an html button and the window for chrome save as pdf or window asking me where my "would be" pdf will be saved and with what name?

Note: Preferred that only chrome's API is used.

Comment: This link may help. http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/how-save-pdf-acrobat-javascript

Comment: I dont think Chrome uses Acrobat.

Comment: Interested to see if anyone else knows. But window.print() is all I can offer. And you can't provide the function any params

Comment: Why not create the rendered PDF yourself, host it on your server and then offer your users a simple download button?

Comment: It's not the same. But if you can live with it great. SVGs are not vector-based, they are images at low resolution. Other images are not resolved at all. Pure XML in browser does not work with CSS, headers/footers are not handled.

Answer (score -1):

you have jsPDF that works with html5